# how to specify the breadth-first strategy or the depth-first strategy in gremlin

Tags: gremlin

The depth-first strategy is the default strategy in Gremlin unless specified otherwise.how to specify the breadth-first strategy?

gremlin language as follow:

```
    g.V().repeat(_,in('edgelabel').simplePath()).times(3).path()
```

Comment: @stephen mallette

Answer (score 1):

Currently when using repeat it defaults to BFS, which is unfortunate given that all other OLTP queries are DFS. There's a ticket to address that: https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/pull/838